# Color transition for C# .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math, colortransform

So I'm trying to make an app with caption buttons: "close, minimize, maximize/restore", but I can't seem to figure out how to transition the R,G,B values of the color to another one smoothly.

I've gotten very good with Timers in C#, but I can't figure out how to calculate the values when transitioning.

My code so far: (the close, minimize, e.t.c stuffs are pre-made rectangles)

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    var pos = e.Location;
    
    if (close.Contains(pos))
    {
        Timer t = new Timer { Interval = 1 };
        t.Tick += delegate (object sender_, EventArgs e_)
        {
            // transition here
        };
        t.Start();
    }
    if (!close.Contains(pos))
    {
        Timer t = new Timer { Interval = 1 };
        t.Tick += delegate (object sender_, EventArgs e_)
        {
            // "reverse" code here
        };
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

***NOTE: I AM NOT ASKING FOR AN ENTIRE CODE SNIPPET***, just some mathematical solutions so I can do this easily.

Comment: You will need to define the nature of the transition. Also: Do have a look at color spaces. The direct route from color1 to color2 usually/often goes through the middle, ie though grey. Maybe a route along the oute parts looks better.. - Finally: It may be a good idea to use float for the calculations and only round to int for display. Another idea is to create a lineargradient brush (maybe with a few extra stop colors) and use it for the transient colors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the button is clicked, compute the time at which you wish the transition to complete. For example, you might take the current time and add 1 second. Store this value.

When the timer tick fires, perform these steps:

1. Compute the distance between the color's current value and its final value
2. Compute the time remaining until the transition is supposed to complete
3. Divide 1 by 2.
4. Nudge the color value by the result of 3.

Repeat this for each tick and you should always hit the final color right on time, even if some of the ticks fail or end up overlapping.

Comment: Thanks, I followed the first 2 steps then modified everything else, and it *worked*!